# There is "dead" unclickable area in the mid of my screen

Tags: linux, mouse-click

I don't know what is wrong but there is a dead area in the middle of my screen.

I can't click nor scroll in that area and it frustrated me so much.
This is the screen capture I took a moment ago. I marked the dead area on red.

How can I fix it?

I'm using Voyager GS distro.

[image: I marked it red]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your machine?

Comment: @Mokubai yup sometimes it don't show up but sometimes it is. i think there is program running in the background but it baffled me why sometimes the problem show up but sometime it dont.

Answer (score 6):

You most likely have an open application that occupies that area of screen (and turned invisible). Try end tasking some of your active programs and check each time when the anomaly disappears.

Comment: xklill might work here - run xkill from a cmd window and click on that area

Comment: Yes, that should be tested.

Comment: @Overmind the problem is idk which programs i should closed there is too much programs running on the task manager

Comment: @JourneymanGeek um.. i used linux n the command is incorrect it said

Comment: xkill? Seems standard on Linux

Comment: sorry but i copy the xklill the one that u post maybe that is why? i try it now?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it doesn't work. it replied with unable to find cursor but the cursor is already changed into "X" and i cant even do anything after that so i reboot my pc for it to turn to normal.

Comment: For the record, I had the same near notification area, it was anydesk, even if I just Quit the program. Using kill would do nothing, and "kill -frame" would kill gnome. I uninstalled the program before knowing about the xprop tip.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [@Overmind's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1191531/518540):

You can run [xprop](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xprop.1.html) to find out more about the application. Just run `xprop` in a terminal, and then click the area with your mouse. In my case, this outputs

> WM_NAME(STRING) = "MySQL Workbench"

so I know which application to close.

Alternatively, run [xkill](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xkill.1.xhtml) as suggested by @JourneymanGeek. **Note**: this terminates the program immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the `xprop` tip. For me, it was **zoom**. Their linux client is a bit dodgy.

Comment: what if they only show the window id? Mine is `windowid # x60000`